# mysqli error cant see what is it error_reporting its not showing anything

Tags: php, html, post, mysqli

OK so I am at the final step of finishing my website. I wanted to create a instalation page so IF i move the website on another host / pma it will create admin account and tables for me automaticly (ok I cant spell this one :/) Now its not showing any error but I cant register account I tried with everything I know and its not working Its always saying that username is already registered but its installation and I removed everything. I checked twice removed twice(or more) but still not working its defenetly something wrong in code. This is the code I will comment with // lines where its checking and showing the error message.

```
<?php   
    if($_POST['registracija'])
    {
        if($_POST['korisnickoreg'] && $_POST['lozinkareg'] && $_POST['imeprezimereg'])
        {
                            $tabelakorisnici = mysqli_query($konekcija,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `korisnici` (
                          `Ime` text NOT NULL,
                          `Lozinka` text NOT NULL,
                          `ImePrezime` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `Admin` int(11) NOT NULL,
                          `Sesija` text NOT NULL,
                          `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
                          `PonedelnikCas1` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PonedelnikCas2` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PonedelnikCas3` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PonedelnikCas4` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PonedelnikCas5` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PonedelnikCas6` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PonedelnikCas7` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `VtornikCas1` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `VtornikCas2` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `VtornikCas3` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `VtornikCas4` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `VtornikCas5` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `VtornikCas6` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `VtornikCas7` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `SredaCas1` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `SredaCas2` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `SredaCas3` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `SredaCas4` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `SredaCas5` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `SredaCas6` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `SredaCas7` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `CetvrtokCas1` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `CetvrtokCas2` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `CetvrtokCas3` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `CetvrtokCas4` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `CetvrtokCas5` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `CetvrtokCas6` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `CetvrtokCas7` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PetokCas1` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PetokCas2` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PetokCas3` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PetokCas4` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PetokCas5` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PetokCas6` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PetokCas7` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PonedelnikZ` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `VtornikZ` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `SredaZ` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `CetvrtokZ` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `PetokZ` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
                        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1");
                        if($tabelakorisnici == '1')
                        {
                            mysqli_query($konekcija, "ALTER TABLE `korisnici` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)");
                            mysqli_query($konekcija, "ALTER TABLE `korisnici` MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1");
                        }
                        if($tabelakorisnici == '1') echo "TABELA 'korisnici' USPESNO KREIRANA.";
                        else if($tabelakorisnici != '1') echo "TABELATA 'korisnici' NEMOZE DA SE KREIRA!";
                        $tabelanovosti = mysqli_query($konekcija, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `novosti` (
                          `Naslov` text NOT NULL,
                          `Tekst` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `Vreme` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `Data` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `Od` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                          `ID` int(11) NOT NULL
                        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");
                        if($tabelanovosti == '1')
                        {
                            mysqli_query($konekcija, "ALTER TABLE `novosti` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)");
                            mysqli_query($konekcija, "ALTER TABLE `novosti` MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1");
                        }       
                mysqli_query($konekcija, 'SET NAMES utf8');
                $korisnicko = mysqli_real_escape_string($konekcija, $_POST['korisnickoreg']);
                $lozinka = mysqli_real_escape_string($konekcija, $_POST['lozinkareg']);
                $imeiprezime = mysqli_real_escape_string($konekcija, $_POST['imeprezimereg']);
                $proverka = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($konekcija, "SELECT * FROM `korisnici` WHERE `Ime`='$korisnicko'"));
                die($proverka);
                if($proverka == '0')
                {
                    if(ctype_alnum($korisnicko) && ctype_alnum($lozinka))
                    {
                        if(strlen($korisicko) <= 20 && strlen($lozinka) <= 60 && strlen($imeiprezime) <= 60)//da ne se pregolemi :D
                        {
                            $sesijaid = hash("sha512", rand() . rand() . rand());
                            mysqli_query($konekcija, 'SET NAMES utf8');
                            mysqli_query($konekcija, "INSERT INTO `korisnici` (`Ime`, `Lozinka`, `ImePrezime`, `Admin`, `Sesija`) VALUES ('$korisnicko', '$lozinka', '$imeiprezime', '0', '$sesijaid')");
                            setcookie("LogiranIme", $korisnicko, time()+60*60*24);//24 saata
                            setcookie("Sesija", $sesijaid, time()+60*60*24);//24 saata                      
                            header('Location: korisnici.php');
                        }else $greskaregister = 1;
                    }else $greskaregister = 2;
                }else $greskaregister = 3;//this is for giving error message see down there in HTML code I have defined it at the top for global usage and set it to 0
        }else $greskaregister = 4;
    }
?>
```

This is html code for posting

```
            <form action = "" method = "post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Корисничко име(Латиница / бројки):&nbsp&nbsp
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="korisnickoreg" class = "loginboxovi"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Лозинка(Латиница / бројки):&nbsp&nbsp
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" name="lozinkareg" class = "loginboxovi"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Име Презиме(Кирилица):&nbsp&nbsp
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="imeprezimereg" class = "loginboxovi"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" name="registracija" value="Регистрирај се" class = "loginboxovikopce"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                                if($greskaregister != 0)
                                {
                                    if($greskaregister == 1)
                                    {
                                        echo "<font color='red'><b>Не внесовте корисничко име или лозинка!";
                                    }
                                    else if($greskaregister == 2)
                                    {
                                        echo "<font color = 'red'><b>Во корисничко име/лозинка се користат недозволени карактери!";
                                    }
                                    else if($greskaregister == 3)
                                    {
                                        echo "<font color= 'red'><b>Тоа корисничко име веќе постои!";//this is That username already exists
                                    }
                                    else if($greskaregister == 4)
                                    {
                                        echo "<font color= 'red'><b>Немате внесено доволно податоци!";
                                    }
                                    $greskaregister == 0;
                                }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: I don't see where you have [PHP error reporting enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: I have it in include but can someone remove this please cuz I find out what is the problem 0.0 I was checking here and I found xD But in notepad++ I lost like an hour

Comment: You should have the option to delete the question under the `tags`.